# Operator BETWEEN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, between

I was writing sub query in stored procedure to get the values between Orders stored as varchar datatype. When i run the query it shows:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I googled a bit and found the problem because of returning more than 1 value in a sub query.

But in my case i need all the values which lies between the given input. Can anybody tell me what way i can achieve this ..

Code:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(
                        ORDER BY po.id) AS SNo ,
       pd.Copies AS Quantity,
       pd.EstUnitPrice AS UniPrice,
       pd.Copies*pd.EstUnitPrice AS Total,

  (SELECT value
   FROM BibContents
   WHERE bibid=pd.BibId
     AND sfld='a'
     AND tagno='245') AS Title,

  (SELECT value
   FROM BibContents
   WHERE bibid=pd.BibId
     AND sfld='a'
     AND tagno='020') AS 'ISSN/ISBN',

  (SELECT value
   FROM BibContents
   WHERE bibid=pd.BibId
     AND sfld='a'
     AND tagno='100')AS Author
FROM  [VibrantMas].[dbo].[PoDetails] AS pd
      INNER JOIN Porders AS po ON po.Id=pd.PoId
WHERE po.No BETWEEN '000021' AND '000024'
```

Comment: tell you what, how about you format your TSQL nicely...

Comment: Sorry for wrong formatting the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `BETWEEN` that is throwing the error but one of the subselects on `BibContents`.

You have two options

- take the easy route and change each `SELECT value` with `SELECT TOP 1 value`
- **get to the root cause** of why one of those subselects is returning multiple records.

  - If it shouldn't return multiple records, you should add a unique constraint to   `BibContents` preventing this from happening in the first place.
  - If multiple records can occur for a given `PoDetails`, you have to decide wich one you'd like to return.
  - If you want all of them returned, you'll have to change the subselects to proper joins.

My advice would be to save yourself from a maintenance nightmare and solve the root cause.

Working out another scheme for `BibContents` wouldn't hurt either. It looks like you've adopted the [EAV model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question) theme wich I think is a [bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066463/should-i-use-eav-model?lq=1)

Comment: @Dhevy - What solution did you end up using?

Comment: Returning single result from PoDetails.