# Should I use EAV database design model or a lot of tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I started a new application and now I am looking at two paths and don't know which is good way to continue.
I am building something like **eCommerce** site. I have a **categories** and **subcategories**. 
The problem is that there are different type of **products** on site and each has different **properties**. And site must be **filterable** by those product properties.
This is my initial database design:

```
Products{ProductId, Name, ProductCategoryId}
ProductCategories{ProductCategoryId, Name, ParentId}
CategoryProperties{CategoryPropertyId, ProductCategoryId, Name}
ProductPropertyValues{ProductId, CategoryPropertyId, Value}
```

Now after some analysis I see that this design is actually **EAV** model and I read that people usually **don't recommend this design.**
It seems that dynamic sql queries are required for everything.
That's one way and I am looking at it right now.

Another way that I see is probably named a *LOT WORK WAY* but if it's better I want  to go there.
To make table

```
Product{ProductId, CategoryId, Name, ManufacturerId}
```

and to make table inheritance in database wich means to make tables like

```
Cpus{ProductId ....}
HardDisks{ProductId ....}
MotherBoards{ProductId ....}
erc. for each product (1 to 1 relation).
```

I understand that this will be a very large database and very large application domain but is it **better, easier and performance better** than the option one with EAV design.

Comment: I don't agree that your initial design is EAV.

Comment: That ProductPropertyValues table is not EAV ?  C'mon.

Comment: Why do you think it's not?

Comment: EAV is an anti-pattern. Avoid it if you can.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan so you think that my other option "Table per product" is better option?

Comment: Yes. You could also consider using an XML column with SQLXML functions for some of the columns that maybe just want to search, but don't need to count or sort on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EAV is rarely a win.  In your case I can see the appeal of EAV given that different categories will have different attributes and this will be hard to manage otherwise.  However, suppose someone wants to search for "all hard drives with more than 3 platters, using a SATA interface, spinning at 10k rpm?"  Your query in EAV will be painful.  If you ever want to support a query like that, EAV is out.

There are other approaches however.  You could consider an XML field with extended data or, if you are on PostgreSQL 9.2, a JSON field (XML is easier to search though).  This would give you a significantly larger range of possible searches without the headaches of EAV.  The tradeoff would be that schema enforcement would be harder.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the issue that force me to ask this question. I have made EAV structure and filtering products by different categories force me to use dynamic sql and a lot pain. So I started to restructure database to smaller tables and for now I am feeling comfortable with my 40 inherited products table. But still analyzing problem...

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066463/should-i-use-eav-model) questions seems to discuss the issue in greater detail.

Apart from performance, extensibility and complexity discussed there, also take into account:

- SQL databases such as SQL Server have full-text search features; so if you have a single field describing the product - full text search will index it and will be able to provide advanced semantic searches
- take a look at no-sql systems that are all the rage right now; scalability should be quite good with them and they provide support for non-structured data such as the one you have. Hadoop and Casandra are good starting points.

Comment: NoSQL databases are not my interests for this project so I can't consider them. By `...single field describing the product ...` Do you mean to add to product all possible properties as columns? That would be table with 1000 columns I can't do that :(

Comment: No, a single column with all these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well work with the EAV model.
We do something similar with a Logistics application. It is built on .net though.
Apart from the tables, your application code has to handle the objects correctly.
See if you can add generic table for each object. It works for us.