# Fact table design guidance for 100s of facts

Tags: data-warehouse, fact-table, datamart

I'm trying to create a datamart for the healthcare application. The facts in the datamart are basically going to be measurements and findings related to heart, and we have 100s of them. Starting from 1000 and can go to as big as 20000 per exam type.

I'm wondering what my design choices for the fact tables are:

Grain: 1 row per patient per exam type.

Some of the choices that I can think of -

1) A big wide fact table with 1000 or more columns.

2) EAV based design - A separate Measure dimension table. This foreign key will go into the fact table and the measure value will be in fact table. So the grain of the fact table will be changed to 1 row per patient per exam type per measurement.

3) Create smaller multiple fact tables per exam type per some other criteria like subgroup. But the end user is going to query across subgroups for that exam type and fact-fact join is not recommended.

4) any other ideas?

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Does a number like 20,000 represent types of measurement, or instances of the same measurement over time? Are all instances of measurement the same data type?

Comment: some of those numeric measurements and some of those are textual lookup type findings. Numeric measurements would have different datatypes depending on measurement.

Answer (score 4):

**1. A big wide fact table with 1000 or more columns.**

One very wide fact table gives end-user **maximum flexibility** if queries are executed directly in the data warehouse. However some considerations should be taken into account, as you might hit some limits depending on a platform.

SQL Server 2014 limits are as per below:

- Bytes per row 8,060. A row-overflow storage might be a solution, however it supports only few column types typically not related to fact nature, i.e. varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant. Also not supported in In-Memory OLTP. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx
- Columns per non-wide table 1024. Wide-tables and sparse columns are solution as columns per wide table limit is 30,000. However the same Bytes per row limit applies. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604(v=sql.120).aspx
- Columns per SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE statement 4,096
- Non-clustered indexes per table 999

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.120).aspx

**2. EAV based design - A separate Measure dimension table. This foreign key will go into the fact table and the measure value will be in fact table. So the grain of the fact table will be changed to 1 row per patient per exam type per measurement.**

According to Kimball, EAV design is called **Fact Normalization**. It may make sense when a number of measurements is *extremely lengthy*, but *sparsely populated* for a given fact and *no computations* are made between facts.

Because facts are normalized therefore:

- Extensibility is very easy, i.e. it's easy to add new measurements without the need to amend the data structure.
- It's good to extract all measurements for one exam and present measurements as rows on the screen.
- It's hard to extract/aggregate/make computation between several measurements (e.g. average HDL to CHOL ration) and present measurements/aggregates/computations as columns, i.e. requires complex WHERE/PIVOTING or multi-joins. SQL makes it difficult to make computations between facts in different rows.
- If primary end-user platform is an OLAP cube then Fact Normalization makes sense. The cubes allows to make computation across any dimension.
- Data importing could be an issue if data format is in a flat style CSV.

This questions is also discussed here [Should I use EAV model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066463/should-i-use-eav-model).

**3) Create smaller multiple fact tables per exam type per some other criteria like subgroup. But the end user is going to query across subgroups for that exam type and fact-fact join is not recommended.**

In some scenarios multiple smaller fact tables perfectly makes sense. One of the reason is if you hit some physical limits set by platform, e.g. Bytes per row.

The facts could be grouped either by subject area, e.g. measurement group/subgroup, or by frequency of usage. Each table could be placed on a separate file group and drive to maximize I/O.

Further, you could duplicate measurements across different fact tables to reduce the need of fact tables join, i.e. put one measurement in a specific measurement subgroup fact table and in frequently used measurement fact table.

However some considerations should be taken into account if there are some specific requirements for data loading. For example, if a record errors out in your ETL to one fact table, you might want to make sure that the corresponding records in the other fact tables are deleted and staged to your error table so you don't end up with any bogus information. This is especially true if end users have their own calculations in the front end tool.

If you use OLAP cubes then multiple fact tables actually becomes a source of a measure group to a specific fact table.

In terms of fact-to-fact join, you (BI application) should never issue SQL that joins two fact tables together across the fact table’s foreign keys. Instead, the technique of Drilling Across two fact tables should be used, where the answer sets from two or more fact tables are separately created, and the results sort-merged on the common row header attribute values to produce the correct result.

More on this topic: http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/04/the-soul-of-the-data-warehouse-part-two-drilling-across/

**4) any other ideas?**

SQL XML or some kind NoSQL could be an option, but the same querying / aggregation / computation / presentation issues exist.

Comment: Thank you drumsta. So are suggesting smaller multiple fact tables would be better? I'm also considering option 1 with lot of junk dimensions. That will reduce fact table length and junk dimensions would be created for textual findings for similar subgroups. What do you think about that?