# How to fetch all columns of table except one

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, multiple-columns

I am fetching data from product detail table but i don't want to fetch all the columns from the table as i want to make a dynamic product detail page which will display the data directly from the table whenever we add a new column so that we don't have to make any changes in the code.

### This is where the data getting display

[image: This is where the data getting display]

### Reference for the table of product detail

[image: Reference for the table of product detail]

Comment: Specify the columns that you want during `SELECT`

Comment: Just specify all the column name(s), which you want to fetch in the `Select`

Comment: Anyways, your table structure seems to be suffering from bad design. Consider normalizing it.

Comment: I agree with @MadhurBhaiya; if you frequently need to add new columns, you should take a good look at the table design. For example a table that only stores product properties might make your application a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You have a horrible table structure. Try something like this...

```
id, field_name, data

CREATE TABLE `fieldstore` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `field_data` varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
```

Example data:
    1, "blend", "bamboo" (The 1 is of course auto-increment).

This way, you can have an unlimited number of field names without having to alter your table structure every time you wanted to add a new column.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your answer, so that OP can understand what you really mean. +1 ; `Create Table` statements would also be handy

Comment: Also worth a read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066463/should-i-use-eav-model