# conditions (where) mysql

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

Table products:

```
id|name
-------
1 |computer
2 |microwave
3 |transl
```

Table product_features:

```
feature          | id_product | feature_value
------------------------------------
count_of_buttons | 1          | 1
count_of_buttons | 2          | 2
count_of_buttons | 3          | 1
color            | 1          | white
color            | 2          | white
color            | 3          | black
```

Pls, how to get all white products with one button?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select product.*

from product
  join product_features as buttons
    on buttons.id_product = product.id
  join product_features as color
    on color.id_product = product.id

where buttons.feature_value = '1'
  and buttons.feature = 'count_of_buttons'

  and color.feature_value = 'white'
  and color.feature = 'color';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    p.id
    p.name
from
    products p
    join (select * from product_features where feature = 'color') colors on (p.id=colors.id_product)
    join (select * from product_features where feature = 'count_of_buttons') buttons on (p.id=buttons.id_product)
where
    colors.feature_value = 'white'
    and buttons.feature_value = 1
```

You might consider reorganizing the product_features table so that you have a separate column for each feature (i.e. a `color` column and a `count_of_buttons` column) so that you have one row for each product. In fact it could all be in the products table.

Comment: the `product_features` table is an example of the **EAV** (Entity-Attribute-Value) approach. There is no need for window functions. Queries usually need many joins (to the same table) with this approach.

Comment: Wouldn't that approach be costly, especially for large tables? RE windowing functions it seemed to make sense at first but now I can't think how they would be handy -- editing answer.

Comment: The problem with EAV is not the cost of JOINs. Having many joins in a query may be slow but it may be quite fast with indexing. There are other issues, like when you have to store many different data types in the same column. There are also referential integrity constraints that are hard (if not impossible) to enforce.

Comment: Check this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question

Comment: How can we prevent a row with `'count_of_buttons', 'purple'` or a `'color',  '73'` ?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
  p.id
FROM products p
JOIN product_features pf
   ON p.id = pf.id
WHERE pf.feature_value = 'white' AND pf.count_of_buttons = 1

Comment: Won't work because the `color` and `count_of_buttons` are different rows in the same column, not different columns in the same row.

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.id, p.name from products p inner join product_features ON p.id=id_product where feature_value='white' and feature='color' and count_of_buttons=1
```

Comment: The OP asked for white products with only one button. This only gives white products.

Comment: @ypercube It's been edited since my comment.  Still won't work though.