# A dynamic content solution for a flexible mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, crm, temp-tables

I've been thinking a lot trying to figure out how to make a flexible system to hold many values trying to avoid the option of adding more fields to table in the future.
The only thing I could think off, is to make a table that will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form_data` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `value` varchar(500) default NULL,
    `form_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

+--------+---------+----------+--------+
|   id   |  name   |  value   | form_id|
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
|  100   |fullname |  Steve   |   1    |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
|  101   |email    |ab@c.com  |   1    |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
|  102   |fullname |  John    |   1    |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
|  103   |email    |cd@c.com  |   1    |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
```

This way, I could save each value in a row, and it would be as dynamic as I'd want.
I'm aware of the bad performance in a very long tables.

Now I've also figured out how to make the View(front end) of the values in a "Regular" table. Looks just like a normal table.

```
+--------+---------+----------+
|  ID    | Email   |Fullname  |
+--------+---------+----------+
|   1    |ab@c.com | Steve    |
+--------+---------+----------+
|   2    |cd@c.com | John     |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Now I want to create a temporary table instead of PHP loops.
Any ideas how to make this work?
How do I create a stored procedure that will receive the `form_id` as parameter and will return a table like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations. You have re-invented the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

This model has existed for quite a while, but has proven to [perform quite bad](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/most-performant-sql-query-needed) in a relational database system. You should probably not use it.

[This answer makes a nice list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question) of the pro and cons of EAV. The biggest pro is what you have discovered, it's easier to design. The biggest con is what I'm telling here: it's worse on performance.

Since usually you design far less often than your queries run, it might be better to think a bit longer while designing, and have faster queries.

Comment: I'm aware of the Bad performance, but the dynamic options covers. it.

Comment: By the way, **never** feel bad about (re)inventing something that already exists: it means your invention was good enough to already be thought of by someone else. Keep going, and one day, you'll improve something or think of something completely new.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL is considered more dynamic
Try the schemaless approach.
this may be a goot starting point:http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/01/schema-free-mysql-vs-nosql/