# What is this type of data transformation called?

Tags: database, normalization, denormalization

Discussing with an coworker about data structures and I was reminded I use to convert from "Schema A" to "Schema B", is this considered "normalization/de-normalization" or schema conversion or what?  Any insight would be appreciated.

"Schema A"

```
TableA
ID KEY Value
------------
1  A   23
1  B   250
2  B   100

TableB
Key Description
---------------
A   Age
B   Weight
```

"Schema B"

```
TableC
ID Age  Weight
--------------
1  23   250
2  NULL 100
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the title. Hope you agree with the edit.

Comment: Schema A is called an EAV schema (EntityAttributeValue). Schema B is a "normal" 3 column table. The operation is called PIVOT(-ing) in SQL terms, or TRANSPOSE in mathematics (and SAS)

Comment: As @usr just reminded me, they are both normalised.  If you're interested in which might suit your need best this might help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question

Answer (score 0):

This is called *pivoting*.

Lacking a better reference I'll link to [SQL Server's implementation of PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The reverse is called *unpivot*.

You don't need special SQL operators to execute them. Pivot can be implemented using aggregates and unpivot can be implemented by joining a table of constants.