# MySQL Relational Database with Large Data Sets Unique to Each User

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am working on a project which involves building a social network-style application allowing users to share inventory/product information within their network (for sourcing).

I am a decent programmer, but I am admittedly not an expert with databases; even more so when it comes to database design.  Currently, user/company information is stored via a relational database scheme in MySQL which is working perfectly.

My problem is that while my relational scheme works brilliantly for user/company information, it is confusing me on how to implement inventory information.  The issue is that each "inventory list" will definitely contain differing attributes specific to the product type, but identical to the attributes of each other product in the list.  My first thought was to create a table for each "inventory list".  However, I feel like this would be very messy and would complicate future attempts at KDD.  I also (**briefly**) considered using a 'master inventory' and storing the information (e.g. the variable categories and data as a JSON string.  But I figured JSON strings MySQL would just become a larger pain in the ass.

My question is essentially how would someone else solve this problem?  Or, more generally, sticking with principles of relational database management, what is the "correct" way to associate unique, large data sets of similar type with a parent user?  The thing is, I know I could easily jerry-build something that would work, but I am genuinely interested in what the consensus is on how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: PArt of how you solve this involves asking how you intend to use these fields that are not standard? If you will only display them, putting the whole description in a varchar or nvarchar (max) field will work, withthe common features that you would query on being inteh table as separate fields. If you need to query vastlky differnt types of attributes, there are other alternatives incudingthe EAV or document database.

Comment: Yeah, I will have to do some manipulation in PHP, then:

Comment: Yeah, I will have to do some manipulation in PHP, then pass it to the Backbone app in the user's browser.  Because the data has to be manipulated on each transaction, I think it would be too processor intensive to pull JSON (or any other VARCHAR) parse it, manipulate it etc.  Plus I feel like storing everything in a VARCHAR will end up becoming a nightmare as inventory data can add-up quickly.

Sorry, my comment above got cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out this post: [Entity Attribute Value Database vs. strict Relational Model Ecommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question)

The way I've always seen this done is to make a base table for inventory that stores universally common fields. A product id, a product name, etc.

Then you have another table that has dynamic attributes. A very popular example of this is Wordpress. If you look at their data model, they use this idea heavily.

One of the good things about this approach is that it's flexible. One of the major negatives is that it's slow and can produce complex code.

I'll throw out an alternative of using a document database. In that case, each document can have a different schema/structure and you can still run queries against them.

Comment: Great Answer.  I will do some reading to decide which solution fits my needs.  Quick question: I feel like an EAV database would fit something like Wordpress because the total number of attributes/data would stay relatively low.  Would this option still be considered viable in a system that could have potentially hundreds of thousands of products, with each between 5 and 10 attributes?

Comment: Actually Wordpress uses it heavily. They have on the order of hundreds of attributes, not just a handful. It is a little surprising and probably at least one of the reasons Wordpress sites can run really slow. One of their _huge_ mistakes (in my opinion) is making the attribute value field a string. If you store an integer, it gets stored as a string and then converted to an integer. Gross.