# SQL Server : how to store and read product specifications (tags) to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need your help.

I am creating an eCommerce website and I hit a wall with product specifications.

I have the following tables

**Items**

```
ItemID    (1231)
ItemName  (Dell Inspiron)
```

**Specs**

```
SpecID    (5342)   (5343)
ItemID    (1231)   (1231)
SpecName  (HDD)    (MEM)
SpecValue (500GB)  (4GB)
```

The values in brackets are table rows.

Is this the best way to store the specs in the database ?

How can I query it later ? Lets say I need all products with `HDD=500GB` and `MEM=4GB` ?

Is it possible to read it from database in C# (asp.net) as an object `Items` that has the sub object `Specs` ?

Is there a way to get all the specs combined in only one `Items` row grouped by `ItemID` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is super broad, you should probably google database design, SQL C# and stuff like that, it's hard to answer so many broad questions.

Answer (score 4):

What you're hinting at is called EAV ([Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)). You can read the Wiki linked, and knowing what to look for should get you started to digg further and find C#/EF/Linq/ASP.Net solutions for specific EAV related questions.

Some good discussion will be right here, eg. [Entity Attribute Value Database vs. strict Relational Model Ecommerce question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question).

The SQL Server CAT team has put forth the [Best Practices for Semantic Data Modeling for Performance and Scalability](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/9/4/d948f981-926e-40fa-a026-5bfcf076d9b9/BPSemanticDBModeling.docx), a must read.

Comment: +1 and for a really horribly bad example of what using EAV can do, [see Simple Talk's article called "Bad CaRMa"](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the best way to store the specs in the database ?

It looks like Item and Spec have a many-to-many relationship. So a better design would be like this:

Item(ItemId PK, ItemName)

ItemSpecs(ItemId, SpecId, SpecValue)

Specs(SpecId PK, SpecName)

> How can I query it later ? Lets say I need all products with HDD=500GB and MEM=4GB ?

```
SELECT i.* FROM Items i, ItemSpecs is1, Specs s1, ItemSpecs is2, Specs s2
WHERE i.ItemId = is1.ItemId
AND is1.SpecId = s1.SpecId
AND s1.SpecName = 'HDD'
AND is1.SpecValue = '500GB'
AND i.ItemId = is2.ItemId
AND is2.SpecId = s2.SpecId
AND s2.SpecName = 'MEM'
AND is2.SpecValue = '4GB'
```

However, normally you would already know the SpecId you're querying for, so you won't need the joins on Specs.

> Is it possible to read it from database in C# (asp.net) as an object Items that has the sub object Specs ?

I'm not sure what you mean by this.

> Is there a way to get all the specs combined in only one Items row grouped by ItemID ?

Only if you know the number of specs in advance or if you dynamically construct your query. The more specs, the more columns the row will have.

Comment: It is a one-to-many relationship. Just because the records have the same value doesn't mean they are the same.

Comment: Wow 8 year old answer and it still holds. How did this great answer only get 1 upvote, is what I'd like to know. @JiulinTeng Looks like you misunderstood my answer. In the proposed implementation it is one to many, but my point is that conceptually this is a many-to-many relationship and should be modeled as such.