# How to get the equivalent using join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables :

**fields_col**

```
---------------------
| id |   type_field |
---------------------
| 1  |    login     |
| 2  |    password  |
| 3  |    login     |
| 4  |    password  |
```

**value_field**

```
----------------------------------
| id | typefieldid | value_field |
----------------------------------
| 1  |      1      |     joe     |
| 2  |      1      |     doe     |
| 3  |      4      |     car     |
| 4  |      3      |     dom     |
| 5  |      2      |     he6     |
| 6  |      2      |     abc     |
| 7  |      3      |     iph     |
| 8  |      1      |     nan     |
| 9  |      4      |     no9     |
```

I expect to get all values where the type is `login`.
Here is the expected output :

```
joe
doe
dom
iph
nan
```

I made up the following query :

```
SELECT value_field 
FROM value_field
WHERE typefieldid IN (SELECT id FROM fields_col WHERE type_field = "login")
```

And it output me the correct value.

I wonder how to use SQL join feature in this case.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/801bc/2/0

Comment: is your `fields_col` correct? It looks like you have duplication for the fields `login` and `password`

Comment: Yes it's correct I didn't put all the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it is done with `JOIN`; Use `ON` clause to connect the tables with their appropriate relationships and add another condition such that `type_field = 'login'`.

```
SELECT vf.value_field 
FROM value_field AS vf 
JOIN fields_col AS fc ON fc.id = vf.typefieldid 
                         AND fc.type_field = 'login'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/801bc/5)

**Additional Tip**: In case of multi-table queries, it is a good practice to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias), for code disambiguation and readability.

Also, your current schema (table structure) is basically EAV (Entity Attribute Value) Pattern. It is *generally* a SQL Anti-pattern, and should be avoided. Check this: [Entity Attribute Value Database vs. strict Relational Model Ecommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/870808/2469308)

Comment: Why some answer gives some INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: @executable `LEFT JOIN` is needed when you want all the rows from the left-side table of the JOIN clause, irrespective of a matching row is found or not.

Comment: A quick research on what an inner join and left join would tell you; it's up to you to decide which one you need.  To add to @MadhurBhaiya's comment, an inner join would require the result row to exist in both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I also see `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` alone

Comment: @executable `INNER JOIN` is same as `JOIN`. Similarly `LEFT JOIN` is same as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT value_field 
FROM value_field v

INNER JOIN fields_col f
  ON f.id = v.typefieldid
  AND f.type_field='login'
```