# Index a MySQL table to search for any columns combination

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am developing a website for car ads. The search is quite complicated as you can search for cars by up to 100 filters (make, model, engine, hp, color, year, 4X4, .....   ).

I have [two models of how I can design the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce)

1- Relational
[image]

2- Entity attribute value

[image]

The entity model seems to be a better fit because:

- It is dynamic (one can add any number of fields without changing schema)
- Faster because we have few indexes `INDEX(key, value, publication_id)` and `INDEX(publication_id)`

**However** when joining the publication table with key_values table (two tables) it returns `N(publcations) * M(KeyValues)` even worse if join with another table (Images) it will be `N(publcations) * M(KeyValues) * Q(Images)` so for **20** publications with 30 key/values and 5 images it will return **2500** rows, ***isn't this a waste of space and memory?***

**On the other hand.**

The relational model seems better in terms of relational design and joining: **10** publications will each have one row in car_options table multiply this by the number of images, say 5 and we will have 50 rows.

Two big issue with this design are:

- It is not dynamic as the Entity Attribute Value.
- I don't know how an index can be designed for such table so that it can be used for any combination of filter options?

**Questions:**

If using the relations model, how to design the index to search for any combination of options ?

If using the EAV model, what are the cons of using long table (Key/Value) instead of a relation model, or it is just find for MySQL to handle such case?

Comment: EAV-stored data can be easily converted to relational-structured output in the query. So EAV have no "too many rows" disadvantage described.

Comment: @Akina how is that?

Comment: Either join copies of EAV table, one copy per one output column, or use GROUP BY and conditional aggregation. Search the forum for pivot realizations in MySQL.

Comment: EAV is flexible, but messy in SQL.  Condolences.